# Multiple PUT actions, asp.net mvc 4 web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build an web api using asp.net mvc 4 for this. Let suppose that we have Books resource. Get, Post, Delete works fine but in case Post I'm a little confused. The way how I want to use PUT is CQRS like: one action PUT for updating Title, another action PUT to update Authors and an other one to make the book favorite. All this PUT actions are overloaded with different types of commands and they have just one parameter. When I try to make a a PUT request to this resource routing from MVC fails, saying that are multiple PUT action that match the request. Could anybody suggest how to configure routing to handle:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(MakeFavorite mf){/*code*/}

public HttpResponseMessage Put(ChangeTitle ct){/*code*/}

public HttpResponseMessage Put(UpdateAuthor ua){/*code*/}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think it is better not to apply RPC here, even David solution has some RPC artifacts.
First of all you should design youe URI structure. For example:

```
/books/{bookId}/favouritestate/{state}  
/books/{bookId}/title/{title}  
/books/{bookId}/author/{author}
```

Then update your routing table to handle this:

```
   routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "BookTitleApiRoute",
                routeTemplate: "books/{bookId}/title/{title}  ",
                defaults: new {controller = "BookTitleController", title = RouteParameter.Optional}
                );
```

Then add some controllers. For example:

```
 public class BookTitleController : ApiController
    {
        // GET /books/{bookId}/title/
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string bookId)
        {
            return your book title
        }
        // PUT /books/{bookId}/title/{title}
        public HttpResponseMessage Put(string bookId,string title)
        {
            update book title and return result
        }

    }
```

You also can interpet relations between objects like that and etc.

Hope this will help ypu to build nice RESTful API =))

Comment: Sorry for the late comment ... This works for Put, but how about if you had multiple Gets or Posts off of the same controller?  Is it a good idea to have multiple posts & gets in the same controller?

Comment: Can you provide example of resource, that needs multiple Gets or Posts? As for Get you can use method override.

Comment: Also there is a PATCH verb that is targeted for partial update. http://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/09/05/patch

Comment: RPC? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Since each function doesn't really have much to do with one another, you should try putting each put method in separate respective controllers.

```
public class MakeFavoriteController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(MakeFavorite mf)
    {
        // Code
    }
}

public class ChangeTitleController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(ChangeTitle ct)
    {
        // Code
    }
}

public class UpdateAuthorController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(UpdateAuthor ua)
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

Comment: I think those downvotes are for RPC style mechanism of your example.

Comment: That is assuming/suggesting that they are in fact not related. You are not answering the question directly.